# Bootstrap menu dropdown not showing dropdown arrow on load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a collapse menu item to show the arrow upon page load, is there a way to do this? Currently on load, it doesn't display the arrow until the user clicks on "Files"

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p><b>Main Menu</b> </p>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse">Files</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled " id="pageSubmenu">
                    <li><a href="#">+Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">+Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">+Music</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>  
        </ul>
```

Here are some screenshots of what is happening

[This is on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thrb4.png)
[This is after I click on "files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Xvg.png)
[Finally this is after I close the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEpwS.png)

As you can see the arrow on the right doesn't appear when the page is loaded. Trying to get it to appear so users know it's a dropdown

thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see a demo on Fiddle or CodePen. Usually, the arrow is showed as an after psedoelement, which updates its content based on the attribute of a-expanded

Comment: https://codepen.io/DigitalDope/pen/rpmjam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add aria-expanded="false" to

```
<a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse">Files</a>
```

So it will be

```
<a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Files</a>
```

This will maintain your current css

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
.dropdown-menu{
border-radius:0px !important;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    border-radius:0px !important;
}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-radius:0px !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
                                   
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Menu Tutorials <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Dropdown Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Dropdown Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dropdown Menu 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">dropdown 1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">dropdown 2</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">dropdown 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">dropdown 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">dropdown 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have two choices :

first choice , by adding aria-expanded="false" to your "a" tag as the following:

```
<a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Files</a>
```

second choice , by using "fontawesome" icon inside your "a" tag as the following:

```
<a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" >Files <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> </a>
```

*if you want to use "fontawesome" don't forget to install "fontawesome" library in your header, see the docs on the following link for more information :

https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont#load-all-styles

i hope this helpful .